# Dynamic Conditional formating based with a custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, spread

Ok, it's a bit of a head scratcher for me.

I am working on a work load spreadsheet and I need to highlight people with different colours depending on their workload so that I could see at glance who's loaded too much and who still has capacity.
Capacity number is just a number of project she or he can handle can be 3 to 5. I store this data in a separate sheet "Resources".
3 colours of load are enough

The problem I am facing is conditional formatting in GS doesn't support pulling data from a separate sheet. Id' rather keep all the raw data outride of the main Overview sheet. But if it's impossible maybe helper columns next to each group of workers would work as well
However, it's important be able to copy the whole row and paste at the end for new projects.

Plus I have difficulty to figure out how to create a formula that works for all names, rather than creating colour conditions for each single name.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example spreadsheet of table and bellow what I envision it should like. I need to be able to see in the Overview sheet at glance who's at their capacity. So as you can see Bobbie is on 6 projects, so he has to be RED. Tom is only on one project and the colour should be something like blue or green. Hope that makes sense  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hJlsH8PndCYrrhgCoL5oUghHQMLL1bgIWomSpEfdEA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly do add your samples in form of text, so that we can test our formulas/codes, thank you.

Comment: @Alex Reds. Just to make sure I understand, do you need the validation base in the developers? And the ones that need to be highlighted with the validation rule are the developers in the "Overview" sheet ? it's that correct?

Comment: Yes Giselle Overview is where I'd like to see at glance the work load and when I switch employees between projects or add them to new ones, I need to see if they are at their full capacity if that makes sense

Comment: I made the sheet editable. Didn't notice it was set to Viewing only. Apologies. You can test it out now

Comment: @AlexReds, I posted an answer, and added an example in "Copy of Overview."

Answer (score 1):

### Quick fix

**Try this** if you want the conditional formatting done in **`Resources`** tab.
Adjust the minpoint and maxpoint in Conditional format rules pannel accordingly

[image]

### Helper table

> **Paste this formula** anywhere to get the **helper table** with the count of each worker occurrence in the range `C2:F`

```
= ArrayFormula({
  "Name", "Work Load";
   FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"-"), IF(
   FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"-")="",,
   COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:F))<>"-")))})
```

[image]

### [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) & formulas - Simple

Similar to [Giselle Valladares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17390145/giselle-valladares), [**answer "2022-08-12 22:00:41Z"**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73340062/timeline#history_fa72bfc5-be96-4f06-802f-91d62b147adc) 
Simple but have a Limitation: a single white space is also highlighted

| Color "Formatting style" | Apply to range | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green | C2:G | =COUNTIF(C2:F,C2)=1 |
| Blue | C2:G | =COUNTIF(C2:F,C2)=2 |
| yellow | C2:G | =COUNTIF(C2:F,C2)=3 |
| Red | C2:G | =COUNTIF(C2:F,C2)>=4 |

### [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) & formulas - Complex

**Try this**

| Color "Formatting style" | Apply to range | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green | C2:G | =ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(Overview!C2:G23, TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"),FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")<>""),FILTER(IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"))),IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")))<>"")=1)))) |
| Blue | C2:G | =ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(Overview!C2:G, TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"),FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")<>""),FILTER(IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"))),IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")))<>"")=2)))) |
| yellow | C2:G | =ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(Overview!C2:G, TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"),FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")<>""),FILTER(IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"))),IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")))<>"")=3)))) |
| Red | C2:G | =ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(Overview!C2:G23, TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"),FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")<>""),FILTER(IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-"))),IF( FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")="",, COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G),FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)<>""), FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"",UNIQUE(FLATTEN(Overview!C2:G))<>"-")))<>"")>3)))) |

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I am afraid I didn't explained myself properly, I need conditional formatting in the Overview sheet. Will it work there?

Comment: The gradations defo look great. it would be nice to use them and automatically apply to the names depending on their work load.

Comment: I am amazed at your formula. How do you even come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found a way to do this. However, it needs a couple of Conditional format rules if you want to do a kind of gradian.

The good thing is that it will not require to be linked to a name. Even if you change the names, it will not affect it.

The rule will look something like this:

[image]

The one that has a capacity of up to 5 will look like this after adding the rules:
[image]

For the ones for developers, I added the 3 columns at the same time, so the formula takes the 3 columns for the capacity count.

[image]

I edited the Sheet called "Copy of Overview." I added the formatting for the  C and D columns.

**Reference:**

- [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was:

First, you applied your conditional formatting to whole columns when your first row is a header.

Second, your NB.SI formulas had the same problem as the first one but also you didn't lock your ranges with "$".

So for managers, the formula must apply to the range C2:C (not C:C) and be written like that:

```
=NB.SI($C$2:$C,C2)>5
```

The ">5" must be modified according to the colors you want.

For the Designer, you can add the function "IF" to the formula as Daniella has more capabilities like this:

```
=SI($G2<>"Daniella";NB.SI($G$2:$G,G2)>3,NB.SI($G$2:$G,G2)>4)
```

[image: Visual result]